# remove all anchors except it's contents?

Tags: jquery

I found that sometimes this code returns `NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

```
$('a').replaceWith(function() {
    return $.text([this]);
});
```

Is it complaining about a case when the anchor does not have any text node? perhaps a child HTML element?

Comment: What parts are you trying to keep? href="this" or <a>this</a>?

Comment: what is your target markup and the desired output

Comment: I think you should use return $.text(this);

Comment: @LJ-C I am trying to remove the anchor tag entirely

Comment: @C-link still returns the error

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am targetting all anchors so anything like `<a href...>anything here text or html</a>` and return `anything here text or html`

Comment: what is the desired output you are looking for

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('a').contents().unwrap()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KLq5w/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: then please update demo with some real world html for comparison. It's not entirely clear what the issue is

Comment: @charlietfl I've provided the real world html which your code and my code brings about different results. http://jsfiddle.net/KLq5w/3/

Comment: there's script in your html that  throws errors, please remove. What are you wanting, text only? No images? Would help to scale your demo html down to just a few links...and show what output you want as well

Comment: basically with my code it seems to remove the empty spacings beside the title of costumes. with your code it seems to retain the empty spacings. I don't know what is causing this.

Comment: mine just unwraps what's inside which is what the subject title of your posts suggested. If you get `text()` of element that has many text nodes in different children, children can be separated by css...no gurantee that `text()` won't cause some merging. Still not clear what output you wnt...and it's been asked numerous times